# WS-Security in Wildfly without Spring and without WS-SecurityPolicy

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wildfly, ws-security

My client suggests that implementing a web service using WS-Policy entries inside the WSDL (using WS-SecurityPolicy standard, which seems to be the recommended way) might cause incompatibility issues with clients that call the web service. My first question is, are his concerns correct? If not, how can I prove to my client that it is safe to use WS? I could not find anything on the subject.

If compatibility issues can indeed occur, I need to find a different way to implement WS-Security requirements (like signing parts etc.) without Spring, using JavaEE APIs. I could not find anything on that subject either. The only thing I could find is about standalone web services but I do not want that, I want a web application and I need to use JavaEE APIs (so no Spring).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pre-existing clients already using this webservice, then yes it will break compatibility if you add WS-Security.

But if no one is using it, or it hasn't been developed yet, how will this cause compatibility issues?

Personally I see WS-Security as rather complex, particular in the area of signing and encryption, so if your client had said that some clients might not have the skills to implement the web service I would have been inclined to agree with him.

Comment: There are pre-existing clients which i do not know how they are implemented but they definitely use ws security. My clients concerns are about implementing the server usin security policy

Comment: you say "they definitely use WS-Security" but don't use WS-SecurityPolicy? That seems very odd, but if so, can you add the current wsp:policy section of your WSDL to the question. You also stated in your question that you want to 'implement' a webservice, but now you say it is already implemented?

Comment: There is a central authority which has published the web service specifications. In it, they do not specify anything about WS-SecurityPolicy. Every participant connects to another participant by implementing the web service and using a central directory to retrieve other participant info (certificates, endpoint urls, etc). The system is already in production so there are already some participants which I do not have knowledge of the implementation. It is possible to implement WS-Security without policy, see http://bit.ly/1LRmIER action based approach.

Comment: I would like to avoid this approach because it is not the recommended way and I could not find any concrete example. So if I can be certain that there will be no incompatibilities I will not use it